# Representation of $S_3$ that is reducible and indecomposable

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, examples-counterexamples

Does someone of you know an easy representation of $S_3$ that is reducible and indecomposable in characteristic 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard example of a reducible indecomposable representation in characteristic $p$ is the two dimensional representation of the cyclic group $C_p$ that sends the generator to the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 &1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. Since $S_3$ has $C_2$ as a quotient, we can compose the quotient map with the representation of $C_2$ to get the desired representation of $S_3$.

It wil send every transposition to $A$ and every other element to the identity.

Comment: Was just about to start typing the exact same example. +1 and thanks for saving me the trouble :-)

Comment: Great, thanks! Nice construction.